# Custom properties for DataRow

Tags: c#, datarow

**What I want to achieve**: I want to have a DataTable with rows of different types with different properties. One example is a sum row at the end of the DataTable (there will be more once this works).
Inspired by the two answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101412/how-to-extend-datarow-and-datatable-in-c-sharp-with-additional-properties-and-me) describing extended DataRow classes (not the accepted one!) I have implemented the following:

```
public class ProjectEffortTable : DataTable
{
    public ProjectEffortTable() : base() { }
    public ProjectEffortTable(String TableName) : base(TableName) { }
    protected ProjectEffortTable(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo Info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext Context) : base (Info, Context) { }
    public ProjectEffortTable(String TableName, String TableNamespace) : base(TableName, TableNamespace) { }

    protected override Type GetRowType()
    {
        return typeof(ProjectEffortRow);
    }
    protected override DataRow NewRowFromBuilder(DataRowBuilder Builder)
    {
        return new ProjectEffortRow(Builder);
    }
}
public class ProjectEffortRow : DataRow
{
    public ProjectEffortRow (DataRowBuilder Builder) : base (Builder)
    {
    }

    public Boolean IsSum { get; set; }
}
```

With the following code I can include a new sum row:

```
var SumRow = ProjectEfforts.NewRow() as ProjectEffortRow;
SumRow.IsSum = true;
// calculate sums for all month columns
foreach (DataColumn Column in ProjectEfforts.Columns)
{
    Decimal Sum = 0;
    foreach (DataRow CurrentRow in ProjectEfforts.Rows)
    {
        if (CurrentRow[Column] is Double)
        {
            Sum += Convert.ToDecimal(CurrentRow[Column]);
        }
    }
    SumRow[Column] = Decimal.Truncate(Sum);
}
ProjectEfforts.Rows.Add(SumRow);
```

**The problem:** The DataTable object can be manipulated by the user (using a DataGridView) and I need to save these changes to a data base in my data model (without saving the sum row).
To check for changes if have the following function:

```
Boolean CheckForChanges()
{
    Boolean Changed = false;

    var ProjectChanges = DataTableObject.GetChanges();
    if (ProjectChanges != null)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < ProjectChanges.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!(ProjectChanges.Rows[i] as ProjectEffortRow).IsSum)
            {
                Changed = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return Changed;
}
```

Unfortunately that method always returns true because it seems that GetChanges() creates a new DataTable where the information of the property is lost.

**What I don't want to do:** I don't want to add columns to the DataTable for each of the properties because this would tightly couple my view with the data model. If I created new columns for each property I would do that in the model and would need to hide all these columns in the view - which I deem quite ugly.

**The question:** Is it possible to somehow create a DataTable containing custom types of DataRows that maintain custom properties?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

After thinking some more I found a solution that works fine so far. I am not sure yet how well it scales but for the sum row I am quite satisfied. The key was to also implement GetChanges with custom code as the information about sum rows is known in that function.
Here's my current implementation:

```
public class ProjectEffortTable : DataTable
{
    public ProjectEffortTable() : base() { }
    public ProjectEffortTable(String TableName) : base(TableName) { }
    protected ProjectEffortTable(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo Info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext Context) : base (Info, Context) { }
    public ProjectEffortTable(String TableName, String TableNamespace) : base(TableName, TableNamespace) { }

    protected override Type GetRowType()
    {
        return typeof(ProjectEffortRow);
    }
    protected override DataRow NewRowFromBuilder(DataRowBuilder Builder)
    {
        return new ProjectEffortRow(Builder);
    }
    public new ProjectEffortTable GetChanges()
    {
        var Changes = Clone() as ProjectEffortTable;
        foreach (ProjectEffortRow CurrentRow in Rows)
        {
            if ((CurrentRow.RowState != DataRowState.Unchanged) && (!CurrentRow.IsSum))
            {
                Changes.ImportRow(CurrentRow);
            }
        }
        if (Changes.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            Changes = null;
        }
        return Changes;
    }
    public new ProjectEffortTable GetChanges(DataRowState RowStates)
    {
        var Changes = Clone() as ProjectEffortTable;
        foreach (ProjectEffortRow CurrentRow in Rows)
        {
            if ((CurrentRow.RowState == RowStates) && (!CurrentRow.IsSum))
            {
                Changes.ImportRow(CurrentRow);
            }
        }
        if (Changes.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            Changes = null;
        }
        return Changes;
    }

    public void AddSumRow()
    {
        // add line with sum for each month column
        var SumRow = NewRow() as ProjectEffortRow;
        SumRow.IsSum = true;
        Rows.Add(SumRow);
        RecalculateSums();
    }
    public Boolean HasSumRow()
    {
        var SumRowFound = false;

        if ((Rows[Rows.Count - 1] as ProjectEffortRow).IsSum)
        {
            SumRowFound = true;
        }
        return SumRowFound;
    }
    public void RemoveSumRow()
    {
        if (HasSumRow())
        {
            Rows[Rows.Count - 1].Delete();
        }
    }

    private void RecalculateSums()
    {
        if (!HasSumRow())
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Recalculation of sum triggered without sum row being present");
        }

        foreach (DataColumn Column in Columns)
        {
            Decimal Sum = 0;
            foreach (ProjectEffortRow CurrentRow in Rows)
            {
                if ((CurrentRow[Column] is Double) && (!CurrentRow.IsSum))
                {
                    Sum += Convert.ToDecimal(CurrentRow[Column]);
                }
            }
            Rows[Rows.Count - 1][Column] = Decimal.Truncate(Sum);
        }
    }
}
```