# Adding Tag in DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagridview, datatable

I am converting a DataGridView to DataTable for some uses in WPF MVVM.
Now, I have this code using the DataGridView with `dgvSample` as the DataGridView:

```
foreach(var transaction in transactionlist)
{
    dgvSample.Rows[0].Tag = transaction;
}
```

Since I am going to store the datagrid content in a DataTable, I have to do something like the following with `dtSample` as the datatable.

```
dtSample.Rows[0].Tag = transaction;
```

And I am having an error since tagging is not available in datatable rows. Is there any possible alternative of doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of using a DataTable you could use a class and have the transaction as a property of the class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101412/how-to-extend-datarow-and-datatable-in-c-sharp-with-additional-properties-and-me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a "Tag" column to the `DataTable`:

   ```
   dtSample.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Tag"));
   ```
2. Set the value of the column like this:

   ```
   dtSample.Rows[0]["Tag"] = "...";
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions

1. Add a column to the DataTable called Tag and store the value in that
2. Create a DataSet, add the DataTable to the DataSet then create a new table Tags with a DataRelation to the original DataTable